# Where is the source code location for np.multiply()

Tags: python, numpy

I can’t seem to find the Github source code for numpy.multiply().

Does anyone have a link to Github for this? Thanks.

Comment: ufunc and umath were combined into _multiarray_umath which is generated during the installation process.  it produces a *.pyd file in ...\site-packages\numpy\core.  You will see the imports in the umath.py file in that same folder

Comment: Thanks @NaN. Can I ask how do you open the umath.py file to see the source code for np.multiply()?

Comment: Hi @sophros, do you know how I can open the umath.py file to see the source code for np.multiply(). Or it would be easier if there was a Github link to the source code. Many thanks!

Comment: @Leockl use Windows explorer, navigate to .......site-packages\numpy\core... umath.py is there... you will be disappointed if you are looking for the actual code

Comment: What are you hoping to find?  or what do you want to do with this code?  Are you trying to understand so behavior?  replicate in a different context or language?

Comment: Thanks @NaN. I had a looked at the umath.py file but the source code for np.multiply() is not there. Also, similarly to the [Github link](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/umath.py), it's not there. Can you let me know why it wouldn't be there and why I will be disappointed if I was to be looking for the actual code. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, I am hoping to read more existing codes (especially establish ones) in order to be able to write my own codes more efficiently

Comment: `multiply` uses compile code, and deeply embedded in the `numpy` base. Even if you can find the essential part(s) it won't help you write better Python.  Do look at numpy code if available (e.g. via the `[source]` link in the docs).  Learn but don't blindly imitate.  For example see my recent `kron` answer.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, the `[source]` link is not in the docs, hence the numpy code is not available there. I find that reading other people codes to see how they are written helps me write my own codes better, rather than just copy and pasting.